# how to use audio file from user in flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, audio, mp3

I am trying to build a flask app in which I need to record audio from the user and then hand the audio back to the server where I want to turn the speech into text. Until now I can record audio from the user and download it as mp3 file if I want to. My question is how do I hand the audio file over to the server? Do I have to download it and then upload it or is there another way.

Comment: In general, you can send the audio data to the server with AJAX, then create a view function to receive and save it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have some examples